# Styled button appearing strange (using Bootstrap, jQuery Mobile) - double text

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm getting this appearance in my form buttons - notice the double text. I'm using a style sheet generated from jQuery Mobile Download Builder (navigation, location push and transitions selected only). It seems to be jQuery Mobile that is causing this. I've tried data-enhanced="false" on the page div but doesn't seem to do anything. I don't want any styling from jQuery, just the navigation for graceful degradation. For styling, I'm using Bootstrap.

See button - http://ma.rtyn.biz/bizness/homepage2/form_button.png

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can stop this from happening? I'd prefer to use a button tag rather than a link as I want it to submit the form without JavaScript.

Comment: reproducing this issue in jsfiddle will make it much easier to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Sorry - here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/bizt/SzALD/

Actually it's even stranger in jsfiddle, it's reproduced the text three times here.

Comment: Add `data-role="none"` to button if you want JQM to untouched it.

Comment: Great, thanks. I see in jsfiddle that makes the difference :)